# Math function from 2 or more $scope like sum, multiple, ect on from Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this database on Firebase:

[image]

And I was wondering how do I suppose to get the summary from two `$scope`?

Sample case:

I tried to get the sum from answer `1` and answer `3` with this Controller

```
  $scope.answer=$firebaseObject(fireBaseData.refUser().child(user.uid).child("answer"));

  $scope.type1= ($scope.answer[1] + $scope.answer[3];
```

but failed when I call it on UI `{{type1}}`:

`$scope.answer[1]:` is supposed to be `54` and `$scope.answer[3]:` is `22`

Comment: what do you have in $scope.answer?

Comment: `{"1":"54","2":"62","3":"22","4":"34","5":"10","6":"6","7":"90","8":"14","9":"80","10":"35","11":"90","12":"40","13":"82","14":"29","15":"78","16":"95","17":"25","18":"70","19":"14","20":"71","21":"16","22":"69","23":"22","24":"79","$id":"answer","$priority":null}` this

Answer (score 0):

problem solve, i did this way

```
$scope.assessment= function () {
            $scope.type1 = (parseInt($scope.answer[3]) + parseInt($scope.answer[12]))/2;
            $scope.type2 = (parseInt($scope.answer[4]) + parseInt($scope.answer[7]))/2;
            $scope.type3 = (parseInt($scope.answer[10]) + parseInt($scope.answer[14]))/2;
            $scope.type4 = (parseInt($scope.answer[8]) + parseInt($scope.answer[11]))/2;
            $scope.type5 = (parseInt($scope.answer[9]) + parseInt($scope.answer[17]))/2;
            $scope.type6 = (parseInt($scope.answer[2]) + parseInt($scope.answer[16]))/2;
            $scope.type7 = (parseInt($scope.answer[1]) + parseInt($scope.answer[15]))/2;
            $scope.type8 = (parseInt($scope.answer[18]) + (100 - parseInt($scope.answer[19])))/2;
            $scope.type9 = (parseInt($scope.answer[5]) + parseInt($scope.answer[13]))/2;
            $scope.type10 = (parseInt($scope.answer[6]) + (100 - parseInt($scope.answer[20])))/2;
            $scope.type11 = ((parseInt($scope.answer[21])) + (parseInt($scope.answer[22])) + (parseInt($scope.answer[23])) + (parseInt($scope.answer[24]) * 20) )/4;

            fireBaseData.refUser().child($scope.user_info.uid).child("result").update({    // set
              type1: $scope.type1,
              type2: $scope.type2,
              type3: $scope.type3,
              type4: $scope.type4,
              type5: $scope.type5,
              type6: $scope.type6,
              type7: $scope.type7,
              type8: $scope.type8,
              type9: $scope.type9,
              type10: $scope.type10

            });
            fireBaseData.refUser().child($scope.user_info.uid).update({    // set
              socialskill: $scope.type11
            });
    };
```